# Powershell - -replace does not replace "{{1}} with specified string

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

When I try to run the following it does not replace "{{1}}" with the string. Instead, it just leaves "{{1}}".

```
$finalreport = $template -replace '{{1}}', $table
```

Below is part of the report in the variable $template where I am trying to replace {{1}} with $table.

```
<tbody>
{{1}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `$template.Replace('{{1}}', $table)` or escape the regex special characters

Comment: Or do not double the curly brackets in the template ( write as `{0}` ) and use the `-f` format operator `$finalreport = $template -f $table`

Comment: `[regex]::escape('{{1}}')` results in `\{\{1}}`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I used the below code and that fixed my issue. Thanks to those that helped!

```
$template.Replace('{{1}}', $table)
```